# Flutter UI challenge

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to create this kind of UI in flutter. with expanded pageview??
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/components/bottom_tabs.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/components/card_image.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/components/expandable_text.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/components/heading.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/screens/card_details/components/card_details_cast.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/screens/card_details/components/card_details_photos.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/screens/card_details/components/card_details_reviews.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/screens/card_details/components/card_details_tabs.dart';


import '../../../components/my_text.dart';


import '../card_details.dart';

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  const Body({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Body> createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  PageController _tabsPageController;
  int _selectedTab = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabsPageController = PageController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabsPageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Image.network(
            "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/film-vault/images/c/c8/Furypost.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20171202094520",
            height: 260,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 100,
            left: 180,
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/icons/play icon.svg",
              color: kwhitecolor,
              height: 50,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200, left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 20),
            child: Column(
            
              children: [
                Row(
    
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    const CardImage(
                      image:
                          "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA4MDU0NTUyN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzQxMzY4MjE@._V1_.jpg",
                      width: 120,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 15),
                    // Text("data"),
                    Column(
                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: const [
                            MyText(
                              "FURY",
                              fontSize: 22,
                              isBold: true,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 2),
                            MyText(
                              "(2014)",
                              fontSize: 14,
                              isBold: true,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const MyText(
                          "Action/Drama/War",
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                         
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 40),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            const Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye_outlined,
                                color: klightgreyColor),
                            const SizedBox(width: 2),
                            const MyText("1.5M", isBold: true),
                            const SizedBox(width: 10),
                            SvgPicture.asset(
                              "assets/icons/comment.svg",
                              height: 21,
                              color: klightgreyColor,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(width: 4),
                            const MyText("1K", isBold: true),
                            const SizedBox(width: 10),
                            SvgPicture.asset(
                              "assets/icons/clock.svg",
                              height: 18,
                              color: klightgreyColor,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(width: 4),
                            const MyText("2h 30min", isBold: true),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
               
                const Heading(
                  "STORYLINE",
                  fontSize: 18,

                  padding: 0,
                  lineColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 68, 68),
                  // fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
               
                const ExpandableText(
                  text:
                      "1945, the Allies are making their final push in the European theater. A battle-hardened Army sergeant nallier (Brad Pitt), leading a Sherman tank and a five-man crew, undertakes a deadly mission behind enemy lines. Hopelessly outnumbered, outgunned and saddled with an inexperienced soldier (Logan Lerman) in their midst, Wardaddy and his men face overwhelming odds as they move to strike at the heart of Nazi Germany.",
                  max: 4,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                CardDetailsBottomTabs(
                  selectedTab: _selectedTab,
                  tabPressed: (num) {
                    _tabsPageController.animateToPage(num,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        curve: Curves.easeOutCubic);
                  },
                ),
                // HERE I WANT TO USE EXPANDED WIDGET INSTEAD OF SIZEDBOX, BUT IT GIVES ME ERROR
                SizedBox(
                  height: 300,
                  child: PageView(
                    controller: _tabsPageController,
                    onPageChanged: (num) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedTab = num;
                      });
                    },
                    children: const [
                      CardDetailsCast(),
                      CardDetailsPhoto(),
                      CardDetailsReview(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is all what I did so far, when I wrap pageview inside expanded widget it gives me error,
So is there any one who could find a way to wrap the pageview with expanded widget???

this is all what I did so far, when I wrap pageview inside expanded widget it gives me error,
So is there any one who could find a way to wrap the pageview with expanded widget???

this is all what I did so far, when I wrap pageview inside expanded widget it gives me error,
So is there any one who could find a way to wrap the pageview with expanded widget???

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far?

Comment: I have added more details and my code, can you please check it out??

Comment: It will be easier if you point the exact issue. Also you might like to animate on appBar, try with CIstomScrollView

Comment: when I wrap pageview inside expanded widget it gives me error, So is there any one who could find a way to wrap the pageview with expanded widget???

Comment: check out the code you can find the pageview

Comment: remove `SingleChildScrollView` you can use `Expanded`

Comment: yeah, but how to scroll in this page

Comment: if i remove the SingleChildScrollView the page is not going be scrolled

Comment: I need to scroll the page

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) with `SliverAppBar`. Example from [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool _pinned = true;
  bool _snap = false;
  bool _floating = false;

// [SliverAppBar]s are typically used in [CustomScrollView.slivers], which in
// turn can be placed in a [Scaffold.body].
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: _pinned,
            snap: _snap,
            floating: _floating,
            expandedHeight: 160.0,
            flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
              background: FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 20,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Scroll to see the SliverAppBar in effect.'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: index.isOdd ? Colors.white : Colors.black12,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('$index', textScaleFactor: 5),
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: OverflowBar(
            overflowAlignment: OverflowBarAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('pinned'),
                  Switch(
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _pinned = val;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _pinned,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('snap'),
                  Switch(
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _snap = val;
                        // Snapping only applies when the app bar is floating.
                        _floating = _floating || _snap;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _snap,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('floating'),
                  Switch(
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _floating = val;
                        _snap = _snap && _floating;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _floating,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please check i have added more details??